# Example of a set of possible outcomes which is not an event

Tags: probability, sigma-algebra

On slide number 6 in this [link](https://www.coursesidekick.com/mathematics/3203541), I found the following lines:

> Not every set of possible outcomes will be called an event. Instead, we will require that the collection of events is a $\sigma$-algebra.

However, I don't know what is the motivation behind using $\sigma$-algebra subsets here and why not every set of possible outcomes will be called an event. In fact, I can't think of any experiment in which a set of possible outcomes isn't an event. For example, if we roll a six-sided die, the sample space (or outcome space if you prefer) is $A=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and normally any subset of $A$ is an event. In other words, any element of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is an event.

If instead, I define the event space to be $\{\varnothing, \{1, 2\}, \{3, 4, 5, 6\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} \}$, then this is a $\sigma$-algebra subset on $A$ but I'm not sure that such event space is valid since some subsets of $A$, for example $\{1, 3\}$ is not included for no particular reason.

So is there any example of a set of possible outcomes which is not an event?

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/636940/919 answers your question.  The motivation comes from stochastic processes and becomes important for uncountable sample spaces.  A standard situation where not all subsets are events is the [Binomial Options Pricing Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model).

Comment: @whuber, thank you so much!